# D3 chord diagram - How do I select a chord?

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am a beginner in D3 . I have to realize a task: I have to color the chords according to a condition. At the moment I just know how to select and modify all the chords.
I would like to know if it is possible to select a particular chord?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while working with `chords` you have to keep in mind that each chord data object has a `source` and a `tagert` with the exact same structure and these properties have information about the link to another group, this link is one-way which mean for every chord you have to change the style of the group to achieve your request, and that can be done with something like :

```
var colorlist = [ "#d7d50bff", "#2876b9ff", "#37b578ff", "#64d882ff"] 
svg.selectAll("name of your group").append("path")
   .style("fill", function(d,i){ return colorslist[i] })
```